# Center a Label vertically within a GridLayout's row in Kivy/KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am new to Kivy/KivyMD. I am trying to create a Scrollable GridLayout, which will be used to show verses. I specifically want to use a 2 column GridLayout. (1 column for English verses and the 2nd column for the same verses regionally translated)

I have got the basic structure going, but for the life of me cannot figure out how to align the row items to the top or center. By default it aligns the row items to the bottom of the row. (As in the figure)

[image]

How can I align my verses (the row items), such that they are top aligned?

My KV file:

```
<VerseItem@MDLabel>
text: "1. I am a verse. I need to be top aligned with my sibling\n"*5
adaptive_height: True
md_bg_color: "blue"

<VerseItem2@MDLabel>
    md_bg_color: "red"
    text: "2 I am a Totally different verse, I need to be top aligned with my sibling"
    adaptive_height: True

<ScratchLayout>
    orientation:'vertical'
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_y: True
        MDGridLayout:
            padding: "10dp"
            spacing: "20dp"
            height: self.minimum_height
            cols:2
            size_hint_y: None
            VerseItem:
            VerseItem2:
            VerseItem:
                text:"The text can change, but must be top aligned"
            VerseItem2:
                text: "Hello, world"*10
            VerseItem:
                text: "Hello, world"*4
            VerseItem2:
                text: "Hello, world"*15
            VerseItem:
            VerseItem2:
            VerseItem:
                text:"The text can change, but must be top aligned"
            VerseItem2:
                text: "Hello, world"*10
            VerseItem:
                text: "Hello, world"*4
            VerseItem2:
                text: "Hello, world"*15
```

My python file:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

class ScratchLayout(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class Example(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        return ScratchLayout()


Example().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using an `MDGridLayout` with 2 columns, just use one column. Then use a widget for each row in the `MDGridLayout`. Here is a modified version of your `kv` file that does that:

```
<VerseRow@MDBoxLayout>:
    adaptive_height: True
    text1: "1. I am a verse. I need to be top aligned with my sibling\n"*5
    text2: "2 I am a Totally different verse, I need to be top aligned with my sibling"
    MDLabel:
        text: root.text1
        adaptive_height: True
        md_bg_color: "blue"
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
    MDLabel:
        text: root.text2
        md_bg_color: "red"
        adaptive_height: True
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}


<ScratchLayout>
    orientation:'vertical'
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_y: True
        MDGridLayout:
            id: grid
            padding: "10dp"
            spacing: "20dp"
            height: self.minimum_height
            size_hint_y: None
            cols:1
            VerseRow:
            VerseRow:
                text1: "The text can change, but must be top aligned"
                text2: "Hello, world"*10
            VerseRow:
                text1: "Hello, world"*4
                text2: "Hello, world"*15
            VerseRow:
            VerseRow:
                text1: "The text can change, but must be top aligned"
                text2: "Hello, world"*10
            VerseRow:
                text1: "Hello, world"*4
                text2: "Hello, world"*15
```

Comment: Thank you! Although I would expect the native GridLayout to have row alignment baked in, this is a nice alternative